# I am getting a The type or namespace name 'listcolumns' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: generics, sharepoint-2010, .net-3.5

Ok, so I have this code which keeps tossing the error above. I am really pulling my hair out trying to figure it out.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;


namespace VarianceList.WebPart1
{
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class WebPart1 : WebPart
{
    private class ListColumns
    {
        public String li_requestDate { get; set; }
        public String li_paymentAmount { get; set; }
        public String li_payeeName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is where the error starts:

```
private List<listcolumns> ReadFromList()
{
List<listcolumns> lcList = new List<listcolumns>();

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://ServerName"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("locationOfWeb"))
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
        SPListItemCollection SpListColl = list.Items;
        foreach (SPListItem item in SpListColl)
        {
            ListColumns lc = new ListColumns();
            if (null != item["Title"])
            {
                if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item["RequestDate"].ToString())))
                {
                    lc.li_requestDate = item["RequestDate"].ToString();
                }
                // . . . and so forth
```

also, right here I am getting the following error:  cannot convert from 'VarianceList.WebPart1.WebPart1.ListColumns' to 'listcolumns'

```
lcList.Add(lc);
            }
        }
    } // using (SPWeb
} // using (SPSite  
return lcList;
}        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is a case-sensitive language. You defined a class `ListColumns`, but you're referring to it as `listcolumns`.

That won't work.

Comment: Of course that was it, that is what I get for copying and pasting code. Thanks a lot!!